# When can we expect Meta SO to have dark mode implemented?

Tags: feature-request, meta, dark-mode

When I go to edit the site preferences in my profile, I see that the theme settings are there, but that only applies to the main SO site right now. It's kind of annoying, as I use Dark Reader to make sites dark where they don't already support it; and because the main SO site supports dark mode, I have it as one of my exceptions. The trouble is, because Meta SO is a subdomain of the main site, it's also excluded, leaving it to be rendered in all of its blinding white glory. (I could flip it around and have it not do dark mode by default and list sites that I want to be made dark, and that would work for Meta SO; but that would result in an unreasonably long site list as I add more and more sites to the list.)

It's been quite a while since we got dark mode on SO, so I would've thought that we'd have it on meta by now.

Comment: Never, probably, meta is not worth the investment anymore. The replacement of meta will probably have it. Just have to wait for the announcement of "the new meta!". And I don't have a lick of proof in that direction by the way, just my gut feeling ever since the employees of Stack Overflow started to feel bullied by meta.